# PHP includes and CSS - Set a background for an included page

Tags: php, css, include

I'm building a website where I'm using PHP includes for a header and a footer. The placement of the footer is dynamic based on the height of the page. So sometimes the footer is 3/4 of the way up the page in my browser with a big white space at the bottom of it. The background of my footer container is a solid color (#333).

Is there a way to set this and only this page to have a background-color?

I've tried to include the background-color css code on the footer page but it applies to the whole page instead of just the footer page that is loaded as part of the include.

Or is there a CSS trick to set the height of my footer container div equal to the remaining height of the browser window upon page load? That may be the best way...

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found the CSS "trick" I was looking for. I basically set up an illusion and modified my CSS and how it handles the background-color style.

http://jsfiddle.net/fXf4K/

```
<body>
    <section id="container">
    <header>This is your header</header>
    <section id="main">This is #main</section>
    <footer>This is your footer</footer>
    </section>
</body>

---------

body {background:#999;}
#container {background:#ff0;width:100%;}
header {}
#main {}
footer {background:#999;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**index.php**

```
<div style="backgroun-color:red;">
    <?php
        include('footer.php')
    ?>
</div>
```

**footer.php**

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Not working for me. This was a good idea though. Makes sense.

Comment: @Matt. what exactly you want..?? you can also add position:fixed to fix footer area...also can add height and etc...what you need.

Comment: I add height:100% and it does nothing. I add position:fixed; and it moves the div to the left side of the page, though it does extend the height of the footer to the rest of the page (I have it centered).  Looking to have the background of my footer page/container to fill out the rest of the page, when the page doesn't push the footer past the bottom of the browser window. I have a background for my container div but it obviously only goes for the height of my div.

Comment: @Matt. if you don't mind can you create fiddle for that...cause without thats its hard to see what is going wrong.

Comment: What is a fiddle? Sorry for my lack of terminology knowledge

Comment: [www.jsfiddle.net/](www.jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you'll have to use javascript to make a sticky footer that has a dynamic height. CSS has no way of adjusting to the changes (except media queries, but that would get messy pretty fast).

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LvNWg/2)

So basically, you set up for the traditional sticky footer (using a push). The height of your footer is then applied to the push, and as a negative bottom margin for your wrap.

To make this work, all elements outside of the provided structure that have height will have to be added to the jQuery equation.

Finally, `if (contentH < adjustedHeight)` makes it where if the content is already stretching the page past the screen's height, it will not fire.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to code this! I will give it a shot tomorrow as it is a little late for me at the moment to work with it. Again, thanks for the coding and I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Tried to give your idea a go and I couldn't get it to work. Did some more research and actually found this: http://jsfiddle.net/fXf4K/ It's just a modification of my CSS. Maybe I didn't provide enough info for you to completely understand what I was trying to do.  But, again, thanks for your work. Working with it actually made me understand a little more about JS. So thank you for that!